# SQL WHERE in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I'm getting unknown column in where clause

```
SELECT `table_1`.*, COUNT(table_2.some_id) AS table2count 
FROM `table_1` 
LEFT JOIN `table_2` ON table_1.id=table_2.some_id 
WHERE (`table2count` > 2)
```

I also tried

```
SELECT `table_1`.*, COUNT(table_2.some_id) AS table2count 
FROM `table_1` 
LEFT JOIN `table_2` ON table_1.id=table_2.some_id AND (`table2count` > 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use aliases in the where clause unless you have a derived table. In this, case what you need is `having` clause.

```
SELECT `table_1`.some_column, COUNT(table_2.some_id) AS table2count 
FROM `table_1` 
LEFT JOIN `table_2` ON table_1.id=table_2.some_id 
group by `table_1`.some_column, table_2.some_id having table2count > 2
```

Whenever you are using `group by`, all the columns in `select` should be part of `group by` except the ones that are part of an aggregate function like `sum`, `count` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
SELECT `table_1`.*
FROM `table_1`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(table_2.some_id)
              FROM table_2
              WHERE table_1.id=table_2.some_id 
              HAVING COUNT(table_2.some_id) > 2);
```